# Do I need to restart Apache if I modified an htaccess file?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

So I changed an htaccess file on my server, and am not seeing the changes. Do I need to restart Apache if I modified an htaccess file?

**Update:**
So I don't think this is my problem. Please see my related question: [Why is my htaccess file preventing access to my MP3 file?](https://serverfault.com/questions/139226/why-is-my-htaccess-file-preventing-access-to-my-mp3-file)

Comment: Am I the only one shocked that this information isn't here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html? (It's in the WP article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess but that's hardly canonical.) @OP: I can't see how it would be necessary, since `.htaccess` files are used by shared hosting providers to allow customers to do their own config.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No you don't. Make sure the htaccess is really loaded. Take a look at your access log, for example `/var/log/apache/access.log`

Comment: Hmm...I don't have an apache directory in /var/log

Comment: Maybe /var/log/apache2/access.log

Comment: I don't have anything in /var/log that looks like Apache logs. Maybe there are no logs?

Comment: on some systems it's `/var/log/httpd-access` and `/var/log/httpd-error`

Comment: depending on how you installed apache it can also end up in /usr/local/apache2/logs or something along those lines

Answer (score 3):

It's already been answered, however you don't need to reload as they are read each time a request is made.

This is why on high performance sites you should avoid use them as you are causing an extra I/O event per request. When you're working with tens of thousands of hits an hour it's just too much overhead.

Coops.